# Are the *uncensored words in "censored" form allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I made an edit to a query's title:

Original title->

```
What the s*!+ do I do to make the 4.2 swipe keyboard stop censoring me?
```

My edited title->

```
How to disable censoring keyboard on Android 4.2.1
```

And my edit was rejected apparantly for reason: `This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.`

I do get it that writing the `s` word like that makes it censored. But lets get real here, even a 12 year old kid knows the real word behind that censoring. People wont pronounce it as `EssStarExclamationPlus`, they will say that complete `S` word *in its original form*. You know how bad the impression gets right? This.Is.StackExchange. I like this site because of its discipline, meaningfullness, helpfulness, and constructiveness. Now writing words as F*ck and S$%+ and etc etc is not really fair (or necessary for that matter) is it?

I mean no one wants people to go with these words in every sentence. Once someone begins using them, its a matter of time until numbers increase eventually. **Just imagine most problems in stackexchange beginning in such a title**..... I am certainly sure most people wont do that, but why even keep this rule? I know people sometimes may go overboard because of frustration due to problems, but I still dont get my edit being rejected. But its not about edit really. I just want to know know why are these allowed, especially here?

In short words, `Are the *uncensored words in "censored" form really allowed here? And if yes, why?`

PS-> Here's the [thread/post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34613/what-the-s-do-i-do-to-make-the-4-2-swipe-keyboard-stop-censoring-me).

Comment: A [similar case](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/96000) happened with me just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your review was auto-rejected by a Moderator none other than [Community ♦](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). Do know that this is a bot (I repeat  a **bot** and not human), so do not take the rejection personally.

#### About the rejection

The mod says:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

If you check this message on Google, you'll see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/what-causes-this-edit-rejection-this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-edit) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where one answerer wrote:

> Someone else edited the question already, and did so in a way that touches the same lines yours does. [It's] a merge conflict, just like with source control systems.

You can verify the quoted answer if you see revisions of the question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/34613/revisions). An another user (Reputation points 2k+; has [edit applies immediately](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege) proposed revision 3 with the changes similar to yours (in the title), although he has fallen back to revision 2 now. One edit had to be forwarded and one to be rejected in that case, which in turn happened to be your edit. Also note that the user who proposed revision 3 was the same user who approved your edit, so no worries at least.

Since the rejection happened not by a user intervention but the way system is designed to handle subsequent edits, you may try to suggest the edit again.

On a side note, considering your history of suggested edits I suggest leaving the question untouched. This issue is now on Meta, so a Moderator or another established/trusted user would possibly try to take care of it.

Read more:

- [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit)
- [Trick the suggested edit queue to force reject items](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270537/trick-the-suggested-edit-queue-to-force-reject-items)
- [Rejected edit question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19777/rejected-edit-question)(see comments in the answer)